# Moving specific data between tables, Access VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I imported an excel spreadsheet into a table (Table2)in Access.  The spreadsheet was actually used as a form, so not very organized. I want to take specific cells and append them in a different table (Table1) 
For example, I would like cell D3 (fourth row, third column) to be moved to a new record in Table1, Field 1.  Then I would like cell  F2 to be moved to the same new record, field 2.

I don't need specific code, but a snippet of something similar would help.  I'm not sure how to start.

This is to be incorporated into a VBA macro

Comment: It would likely be better to take the data directly from Excel - you will not get good results importing non-tabular data into access.

Comment: Look at ado and/or SQL using VBA that will be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I would show code, but have none to speak of at the moment, I am trying to use SQL and looking into ADO, Thanks, @Nathan_sav51